# How to select group by with Regex

Tags: sql, regex, group-by, grafana, clickhouse

I've a table with the columns: `itime, service, count`.

I can write such a SQL to query some result:

```
SELECT
    toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(itime)) * 1000 as t,
    service,
    sum(count)
FROM myTable
WHERE
    -- aaa and bbb are two integers
    itime BETWEEN toDateTime(aaa) AND toDateTime(bbb)
    and service like 'mySvr_%'
GROUP BY
    service,
    t
ORDER BY t
```

It works as expected.

For the column `service`, the contents always start with `mySvr_`, such as `mySvr_101`, `mySvr_102`, `mySvr_201`, `mySvr_202`.

Now, I want to `group by` the `service` with some regular expression so that the result will be `group by` like this: `mySvr_1xx`, `mySvr_2xx`, `mySvr_3xx` etc.

But I don't know how. Could someone help me?

Comment: regex support is a product specific feature. What is your DBMS?

Comment: @Serg Well, in fact I'm working on Grafana, which can fetch data from ClickHouse. I'm writing some SQLs on Grafana to visualize the data in ClickHouse.

Comment: @Yves, you are no using Regex. Regex stands for Regular expressions, and your query only contains a pattern to look for in the like expression. Are you sure that `%` is the right character for your sql engine ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the case statements to specify the pattern to get desired output using GROUP BY and LIKE:

For the below table,

```
    >>SELECT * FROM temp_table;
    +-------+------------+-------+
    | itime | service    | count |
    +-------+------------+-------+
    |     1 | mySvr_1234 |     2 |
    |     2 | mySvr_2123 |     3 |
    |     1 | mySvr_1233 |     4 |
    |     4 | mySvr_3212 |     3 |
    |     5 | mySvr_2317 |     2 |
    +-------+------------+-------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the code is as follows:

```
    SELECT service,count(*),
     CASE
       WHEN service LIKE 'mySvr_1%' THEN '1st'
       WHEN service LIKE 'mySvr_2%' THEN '2nd'
       ELSE '3rd'
     END AS group_by_result
    FROM stackOverflow
    GROUP BY
     CASE
       WHEN service LIKE 'mySvr_1%' THEN '1st'
       WHEN service LIKE 'mySvr_2%' THEN '2nd'
       ELSE '3rd'
     END;
```